# In a physical pen test, is there a way to figure out FOV of a tinted dome camera?

Tags: physical, video

With bullet cameras, this is easy.  You look which way they are pointing and then either guess their FOV, or even look them up based on how the model they appear to be.

Most dome cameras are behind tinted glass and it's hard to see where they are pointed at.

Knowing where a camera is looking is important during reconnaissance because it lets you stay out of sight later.

Bonus question:  Is there a way to track this in real time for cameras that can pivot 360 degrees within the dome?

Comment: So, "Is there a way to see where a camera is pointed when it is behind tinted glass?" This is one of those physical security questions that I think is beyond the scope of the site.

Comment: Is the camera itself within the scope of the pentest ? Then I would start by scanning wifi traffic, it's possible the camera is wifi-enabled and a legitimate target :)

Comment: @schroeder securing site, building or office is an operation that must be carried out in IS security. The OP question could be seen how to remediate a weakness at some security control.

Comment: Additional tip: use jamming techniques or deauth the camera from wifi if you can. While the camera may be unable to transmit for a moment footage may still be recorded though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it's dark, try wearing IR goggles or using a near infrared camera. Most of those security cameras have IR LEDs illuminating in the direction of their focus.

Comment: That really depends on the quality of the camera. As you said "most", there is a large number that do not have integrated IR LEDs. Sometimes it's preferable to have a standalone IR illuminator mounted elsewhere. Also low quality cameras sometimes do not have the IR matching their FoV very well (but that could make it easier for you to stay in the shadows).

Comment: Actually, I should take a step back. Using IR LEDs inside a smoked dome may be a bad idea to begin with. Manufacturers warn about internal reflections and recommend disabling the LEDs if using a smoked dome.